# Calling jenkins shared library fails with signature mismatch error

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I created a simple groovy script in shared library to update the build details

```
def call(body) {
  currentBuild.displayName = body.displayName
  currentBuild.description = body.description
}
```

I call `UpdateBuildDetails` from pipeline step

```
UpdateBuildDetails ([displayName: params.SERVICE_NAME, 
        description: 'Test'])
```

Here is the error. Can someone advise what I am missing:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: UpdateBuildDetails.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[displayName:update-service, description:Test]]
Possible solutions: call(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), wait(), any(), wait(long), main([Ljava.lang.String;), each(groovy.lang.Closure)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
```

Comment: Typically you either pass a Closure or Map type for a method defined like that. Try converting your input into a Map instead of a LinkedHashMap: `UpdateBuildDetails(displayName: params.SERVICE_NAME,  description: 'Test')`.

Comment: You could explicitly declaring the type of `body` : `def call(Map body) {`